# How to disable Rails test parallelization *just* for system tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm finding that the default test parallelization makes chromedriver tests highly unreliable. But I'd like to keep other tests parallel.

I've tried this in `application_system_test_case.rb`:

```rb
class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  parallelize(workers: 1)
  # ...
end
```

...but it doesn't seem to override the default.

I'm currently using:

```
PARALLEL_WORKERS=1 rails test:system
```

...but I'm looking for a way to hardcode this into the project in such a way that someone else doesn't have to "just know" to always set that env var for system tests.

Comment: Could you use a shell script to set that variable before launching the tests?

Comment: Why not set the `PARALLEL_WORKERS` ENV var to 1 just for those tests? 
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3.1/classes/ActiveSupport/TestCase.html#method-c-parallelize
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83217025a171593547d1268651b446d3533e2019/activesupport/lib/active_support/test_case.rb#L74
You could set it in a required file that you use for all those tests

Answer (score 3):

I would run two separate process, e.g. a `bin/test` with:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

rails test test/models test/controllers ...

PARALLEL_WORKERS=1 rails test:system
```

Or maybe fix the root cause of the flakiness of the system tests running in parallel

Answer (score 0):

I agree that maybe having a separate script for groups of tests.

Something like:

```html
/system_tests.sh

#!/bin/bash
set -e

# run tests
time npm test -- --maxWorkers=1

rspec --pattern "spec/system/*_spec.rb"



/all_other_tests.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# run tests
time npm test -- --maxWorkers=8

rspec --p --exclude-pattern "spec/system/**"
```

Something along those lines, and then calling each script from your CI config. I'm guessing this question is long-answered, but perhaps the answer and some options to think about and config for oneself will be useful for someone else.